# How do I access a dynamic property in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I've created a dynamic property in the Designer interface. How do I access this property in my code?

I don't see any properties listed with the name I've provided. I've found a dynamicPropertyNames property that contains a QByteArray object and the name I provided, but I cannot figure out how to access the data I stored (nor do I know if this is even the correct place to be querying).

Thanks!

Comment: If you know the name of the property, from the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qobject.html#property) it sounds like the `QObject.property (self, str <name>)` method would be used to access it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tested this and it returned to me a QVariant object. I've never been able to figure this things out in the past. Just did some searching about them again and I've tried .toString and .toPyObject (the dynamic property is set to be a string) but neither is returning the value I have stored. Calling .toString returns an empty string.

Comment: Nevermind. I'm an idiot. Was querying the wrong object. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add custom attribute to QCheckBox widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652828/add-custom-attribute-to-qcheckbox-widget)

Answer (score 0):

Just because I had a similar problem and the reason wasn't a wrong object: The property's content can be accessed with toString().

Answer (score -1):

this answer is just for myself, tried to reproduce the question and answer it.

Here the QtDesigner generated code for a Mainwindow with a DynamicPropierty,

```
main_win.py :
```

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'main_win.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.12.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 20, 261, 131))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 29))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.setProperty("Prova-proprieta", _translate("MainWindow", "valore_pp"))   ### here the dynamic property created in the Designer interface
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

here my code printing the value of the dynamic property,

```
main.py :
```

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton

from main_win import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        
        print('from inside init : ', self.property('Prova-proprieta'))
        
        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_1_Pressed)
        
    
    def pushButton_1_Pressed(self):
        
        self.setProperty('Prova-proprieta', 'changed')  
        print('from PushButton : ', self.property('Prova-proprieta'))
        
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   
    window = MainWindow()
    
    print('from loop : ',window.property('Prova-proprieta'))
    
    window.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Let me know if it right for You

Comment: @musicamante sorry to bother, could you check whats wrong with my answer ? then self.property('Prova-proprieta') return a string , is there a way to get the property object somehow ?