# Add custom attribute to QCheckBox widget

Tags: pyqt, attr, qwidget

I have (I think) a simple question but haven't had much luck trying to find an answer. Really new to pyqt!

I am dynamically adding a number of QtGui.QCheckBox() widgets to a gridLayout based on a number of factors. My question is, how can I add a custom attr to each chkbox widget? I want to store a few custom things inside each qt widget.

Thanks for any help. A basic example would be most useful.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just subclass the `QCheckBox` class. For example:

```
class MyCheckBox(QtGui.QCheckBox):
    def __init__(self, my_param, *args, **kwargs):
        QtGui.QCheckBox.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.custom_param = my_param
```

Here we override the `__init__` method which is called automatically when you instantiate the class. We add an extra parameter `my_param` to the signature and then collect any arguments and keyword arguments specified into `args` and `kwargs`.

In our new `__init__` method, we first call the original `QCheckBox.__init__` passing a reference to the new object `self` and unpacking the arguments are keyword arguments we captured. We then save the new parameter passed in an an instance attribute.

Now that you have this new class, if you previously created (instantiated) checkbox's by calling `x = QtGui.QCheckBox('text, parent)` you would now call `x = MyCheckBox(my_param, 'text', parent)` and you could access your parameter via `x.custom_param`.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the `.setProperty()` method, aka Dynamic Properties:

```py
self.the_wdiget.setProperty("my_string", "hello")
self.the_wdiget.setProperty("my_bool", True)
self.the_wdiget.setProperty("my_int", 10)
self.the_wdiget.setProperty("my_stringList", ['sl1', 'sl2', 'sl3'])

# And get it by:

self.the_widget.property("my_bool") # etc.
```

Strings can also be set to translateable. E.g.

```
self.the_widget.setProperty("my_string", _translate("Dialog", "hello"))
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty

Also see:

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/qt_properties.html